# How to write Java code for AES GCM Decryption using authentication tags

Tags: java, encryption, aes-gcm, node-crypto

I am building a Java SDK for which I need to write a service to decrypt cipher text using initialVector, authenticationTag and secretKey. I am taking reference from equivalent node SDK. The JavaScript code is as follows using the *crypt* package of [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js).

```
export const decryptSymmetric128BitHexKeyUTF8 = ({ ciphertext, iv, tag, key }: IDecryptSymmetric128BitHexKeyUTF8Input) => {
  const ALGORITHM = 'aes-256-gcm';

  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
    ALGORITHM,
    key,
    Buffer.from(iv, 'base64')
  );
  decipher.setAuthTag(Buffer.from(tag, 'base64'));

  let cleartext = decipher.update(ciphertext, 'base64', 'utf8');
  cleartext += decipher.final('utf8');

  return cleartext;
}
```

I am trying to write equivalent Java code, but I am struggling for the same as I don't know how to use authentication tags in Java during decryption. I am using Java 8. How can I write Java code for the same?

Here is the test data.

```
cipherText: 2LPVwa7s4+xyd8KF94r07TOCaOdf4X90NWqhHQCpoJGT+T3TYjKCWf3V+A==
iv: S4/yimaF8bu0jQW9uagIJA==
tag: L6BtTic18dd4fNL2maytFA==
key: password1232asdfpassword1232asdf
expectedPlainText: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: Ciphertext and tag are usually concatenated in Java (JCA/JCE) (ciphertext|tag). Your sample data contains ciphertext and tag separated, i.e. for decryption with Java they have to be concatenated (as raw data, i.e. after Base64 decoding). Note that for GCM a 12 bytes IV is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Decryptor {

    public static String decryptSymmetric128BitHexKeyUTF8(String ciphertext, String iv, String tag, String key) throws Exception {
        String algorithm = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";

        byte[] ivBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(iv);
        byte[] tagBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(tag);
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, ivBytes);
        
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmParameterSpec);
        cipher.updateAAD(tagBytes);
        
        byte[] ciphertextBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertext);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextBytes);
        
        return new String(decryptedBytes, "UTF-8");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String ciphertext = "2LPVwa7s4+xyd8KF94r07TOCaOdf4X90NWqhHQCpoJGT+T3TYjKCWf3V+A==";
        String iv = "S4/yimaF8bu0jQW9uagIJA==";
        String tag = "L6BtTic18dd4fNL2maytFA==";
        String key = "password1232asdfpassword1232asdf";
        
        String decryptedText = decryptSymmetric128BitHexKeyUTF8(ciphertext, iv, tag, key);
        System.out.println(decryptedText);
    }
}
```

also make sure to have the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) installed in your Java runtime environment, as the "AES/GCM/NoPadding" transformation requires it.

The decryptSymmetric128BitHexKeyUTF8 method takes the ciphertext, iv, tag, and key as input parameters and returns the decrypted plaintext as a string. It decodes the Base64-encoded inputs, initializes the cipher with the secret key and parameters, updates the associated authenticated data (tag), and performs the decryption using doFinal. Finally, it converts the decrypted bytes back to a UTF-8 encoded string.

In the main method, you can test the decryption by providing the test data you provided. The decrypted text should match the expected plain text you mentioned.

Hope this work fine with you...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Mohamad. I tried the code you shared, It's giving tag mismatch exception to me: 
`Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!`

Comment: You are confusing AAD (additional associated data) and authentication tag. The AAD are passed in `updateAAD()`, and ciphertext and tag must be concatenated. The sample data does not contain AAD, so there must be no `updateAAD()` call.

Comment: I tried concatenation of `ciphertext = ciphertext + tag;` before doing Base64Decode and then removed the`updateAAD()` call as well. Now I am getting following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 60`

Comment: @thatman - Did you concatenate the raw data or the Base64 encoded data? You have to **concatenate the raw data**, i.e. first the ciphertext and tag have to be Base64 decoded, then the two `byte[]` have to be concatenated, s. online here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/IXj